# JavaScript don't hide text area in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, textarea, visibility

I have strange problem with Javascript, I am trying to implement system to update some stuff, and when I press button I want to hide everything except 'MainContent_UpdateProgress', but text area  is still visible.

Text area in asp.net looks like this:

```
<textarea runat="server" id="serverOutputTextArea" cols="50" rows="30" name="serverOutputTextArea" visible="false">
```

Javascript code:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
var postBackElement;
function InitializeRequest(sender, args) {
    if (prm.get_isInAsyncPostBack())
        args.set_cancel(true);
    postBackElement = args.get_postBackElement();

    if (postBackElement.id == 'MainContent_UpdateAnalysisSystem') 
    {
        $get('MainContent_serverOutputTextArea').style.display = 'none'; //Doesn't work

        $get('MainContent_UpdateProgress').style.display = 'block'; //Works
        $get('MainContent_ProcessingStatus_Label').style.display = 'none'; //Works
        $get('MainContent_ShowDetails_Button').style.display = 'none';  //Works
    }
}
```

Question would be, what is different in textarea ?

Comment: Is the client ID of the text area 'MainContent_UpdateAnalysisSystem' its not get something like 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MainContent_UpdateAnalysisSystem'

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked in the browser's source code to see what the actual id of the textarea is?  It might be that you have it placed within some other element and it has inherited a longer id.

Otherwise, you can get the id by using this: `<%= serverOutputTextArea.ClientID%>`

The javascript line would look like this:

```
$get('<%= serverOutputTextArea.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: I noticed @Fabio-Milheiro updated answer, and he's right. The problem you have is that you are user `visible="false"` on a control that that has `runat="server"`. That means that the control is never rendered, and the javascript can't find it. If you change `visible="true"` to `style="display: none;"` it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Just to confirm: Is MainContent_serverOutputTextArea the id of the textarea?

If yes, can you go to Firebug and try setting the display style attribute to none? Or out of despair try visibility=hidden.

But ultimately, you need to make sure that $get is selecting the correct element in the DOM.

### UPDATE

Mmmmm... I think I know what's going on. You have:

```
<textarea runat="server" id="serverOutputTextArea" ... visible="false">
```

You added the runat="server" to the textarea so it'll be a server control and if the Visible property is false, it simply won't be rendered to the HTML.

Do you know what this means? If it's not rendered, your JavaScript won't be able to see it and select. Set the Visible property to true and it will work.

Comment: Changed visible to true but still same thing. It works when I change CSS. But how to toggle CSS? because I need to show it later.

Comment: If you want to toggle the CSS I would recommend you use JQuery. You can find it [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery). Set it up like this `<script src="http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery"></script>` and then you simple call the `toggle` function like this `$(#'<%= serverOutputTextArea.ClientID %>').toggle()`

Comment: @Full_int, did confirm that the textarea id is the one you're looking for?